# I need help to prove this inequality because I am having problems

Tags: inequality

I need help solving the following:
$$
\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{n+1}<\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^n, n \geq 1 \quad \mathrm{and} \quad 0<x<y 
$$

Comment: Perhaps the $x/y$ is distracting you. Call it $w$. We are interested in $w^{n+1}\lt w^n$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $y>x>0$ implies $x/y < 1$. Then write
$$
\left( \frac{x}{y} \right)^{n+1} = \left( \frac{x}{y} \right)^{n} \left( \frac{x}{y} \right)
$$

and remember that the last factor in the LHS is less than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $0 < x < y$,
$0 < x/y < 1$.
Let $w = x/y$.
You want to show
$w^{n+1} < w^n$
where $n \ge 1$.

Since $w > 0$, $w^{n+1}>0$ and $w^n> 0$.
So we can divide both sides of the inequality by $w^n$
and we get $w < 1$.

Since this is true by assumption,
the inequality is true.

If you want, you can convert this to a direct proof:

Since $0 < w < 1$,
$0 < w^n < 1$.
Multiplying both sides of
$w < 1$ by $w^n$
gives $w^{n+1} < w^n$.